# UWP Scrolling ListView on touchscreen doesn't work

Tags: c#, listview, scroll, uwp, touch

I'm trying to design an UWP App for a tablet and one of the elements I'm using is a ListView. When I'm scrolling with a mouse inside the ListView it works, but if I'm trying to scroll on a touchscreen the ListView automatically snaps back to the default position. How can I solve this problem?

```
    <ListView x:Name="PlayerListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="404" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Height="620" Margin="-3,0,0,0">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                   <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                       <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                       <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#0078D7" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ListViewItem.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Content1" />
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <Grid>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="listItem1" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" />
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content1" />                                     
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: can you share a demo vid of what exactly is happening

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue with above code snippet.My UWP app target 16299 and the touch device OS version is 15254. Please provide more details about your testing environment.